# Кавычки с иностранными названиями и цитатами

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, заимствования, цитата, оформление-цитат

Измучила все справочники, единого мнения не вижу.
Смотрите. Английские названия (Excel, Google) в кавычки по рекомендации, к примеру, Грамоты.ру не берутся. По цитатам я чёткого обозначения не вижу, любые цитаты мы обычно берём в кавычки. То есть можно предположить, что при распространённости английской конструкции кавычки нужны (большая цитата), а если речь о названии из одного-двух слов, то не нужны.
Но названия бывают достаточно распространены — например, названия каких-нибудь программных команд. Ну что-нибудь вроде "Add a new card on this board". Я даже при формулировке вопроса сейчас автоматически заключаю фразу в кавычки, но нужно ли это делать?

Comment: А не смешиваются ли тут вопросы к разным требованиям: к правилам русской пунктуации и к полиграфическим правилам?

Answer (score 2):

*Английские названия (Excel, Google) в кавычки по рекомендации, к примеру, Грамоты.ру не берутся.*

Совершенно верно.
1. "Полагаем, что в бытовом употреблении (при передаче на письме разговорной речи) допустимо написание строчными без кавычек: *пост в фейсбуке, проверить слово на грамоте, рекламная ссылка из гугла, фото в инстаграме* (здесь возможна аналогия с пунктами правил, описывающими бытовое употребление названий торговых марок, изделий и товаров)".
[Как пишутся названия сайтов?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/52-internet)
2. "Не заключаются в кавычки написанные латиницей названия: *сок Global Village, пиво Staropramen, оливки Oro Verde, парфюмерная вода Christian Lacroix Rouge, гель для душа Palmolive, джинсы Armani, куртка Dolce Gabbana".*
[Как правильно употреблять кавычки в собственных наименованиях](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/75-kav2)

*То есть можно предположить, что при распространённости английской конструкции кавычки нужны (большая цитата), а если речь о названии из одного-двух слов, то не нужны.*

Неверные рассуждения — мне кажется, что Вы путаете понятия "цитата" и "название".
Для обрамления цитаты кавычками или выделения ее особым шрифтом не важно, какую она имеет длину.
[Техника цитирования и редакционное оформление цитат](http://genling.ru/books/item/f00/s00/z0000026/st055.shtml)

[**Названия программ**](https://www.proacton.ru/about-internet/terms-glossary) и операционных систем пишутся без кавычек (также независимо от длины; см. п. 1): Microsoft Office PowerPoint, Android Native Development Kit, WordPress API.

Answer (score 1):

Цитаты, конечно, надо брать в кавычки. Причём в британском английском предпочтительны одиночные кавычки. В названиях пишут с большой буквы каждое слово, кроме союзов и предлогов, и не берут их в кавычки в английском тексте, а в русском это же распространяется на названия, написанные латиницей (не только на английском, смотрите [этот](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=297688) вопрос).

Обычно не берут в кавычки названия компаний, что же касается названия программных команд, то мне кажется, что это уже другой случай и кавычки нужны.

Напомню, что там, где это доступно, можно заменять закавычивание выражения или цитаты выделением его курсивом и/или жирным шрифтом. Однако если тем же способом выделены ещё какие-то, например, значимые слова, то может возникнуть путаница.

Comment: Британские одиночные кавычки не ставятся в русском тексте.

Comment: @АнастасияСпивак: возможно, а как в этом убедиться?

Comment: Потому что эта цитата становится частью русского текста и действует по законам русской пунктуации.

Comment: Я понимаю, но есть такие рекомендации где-то?